# drop_caches hangs for 1-2 min and maxes cpu before completing

Tags: 18.04, cache

If I have been logged into the Ubuntu 18.04 graphical console for a while and run either:

```
echo 2 >| /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo 3 >| /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

the process takes almost 2 minutes, whereas it is supposed to be nearly instantaneous. This in turn causes 'logout' to hang for more than a minute. At the same time the CPU pegs at 100%.

This happens even if run the commands repeatedly. However, echoing `1` is almost instantaneous.

If I log out of the graphical console, then `dump_cache` becomes almost instantaneous. If I log back in to the graphical console, `dump_cache` starts taking a couple of seconds but over time will revert to 1-2 minutes again -- not sure though what triggers that change.

I don't have anything running in the console itself other than 2 xterm windows and whatever background processes launch automatically with Ubuntu 18.04

More generally, I am not anything other than a few screen sessions, ssh client sessions, and emacs.

Free shows very little memory or cache usage:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            39G        4.7G         33G        209M        1.3G         33G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Root and system files are stored on SSD so writing cached files should be super-quick.

CPU usage as shown by `htop` is < 10% on all 4 processors.

- Any idea what could be causing this?
- And even if the first dump_cache takes a while due to accumulated 'stuff', why would a second dump_cache that follows immediately take the same amount of time?
- What could possible be taking almost 2 minutes to dump given that there are <2GB of cache and my disk is a fast Samsung SSD?